# Is there a html attribute to store meta information about a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<li>` tag and I want to have some info associated with it so that a piece of JavaScript can access it i.e. `<li id='someVal' class='someVal' meta='additionalInfo'>`

I would like to access the meta information through jQuery as follows `$('#someVal').attr('meta')`

is there a attribute like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use jQuery's `attr()` method

```
$(<selector>).attr('name','value');
```

and retrieve with

```
$(<selector>).attr('name');
```

You can add any name to the DOM element. I am generally a fan of using such meta attributes if it makes sense to add it to the DOM element.

Say your app shows the numnber of schools in it. I will probably have a div with an attribute `school` and set the id of the school as the value.

I know it is very similar to data but my rule of thumb use "attr" to extract metadata that's been added to the markup and use "data" to get/set dynamic application state.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to add data to an element through jQuery:

```
$(element).data('name', 'value');
```

The data can be retrieved using:

```
$(element).data('name');
```

Or are you not trying to add data through jQuery?

In HTML5 there is also the possibility of custom data as I found on the web: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

However as HTML5 is still a draft no guarantees there.

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object." http://api.jquery.com/data/